# Show lines only above latest(today's) price (TradingView Pine Script)

Tags: pine-script

I am creating lines of resistance using pivothigh and I would like to only show lines above the current(today's) price. I understand that the script works through each bar at a time, but is there a way to get the current price? Alternatively, is there a "length" variable/function for a series so that I could iterate through lines and delete them if they are lower than the current price?

Answer (score 0):

`close` refers to last price action of the current bar. Just keep an eye on it and you will see.

There is no variable/function to get the length of a series. However, you can implement a counter for that. Everytime you create a line, increase the counter. Have a look at the second example [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-keep-only-the-last-x-labels-or-lines).

Comment: Looks there is a maximum for loop iteration of 300, however, my label count is 685. I decided to do labels for debugging purposes. Though strangely I only see about 30 stray labels on the far left.